# pass and compare external variable in awk command

Tags: awk

how to pass and compare an external variable in awk command? is it also dependent on unix shell that we are using

1. I am trying to do :

   ```
   mgrid=`echo $file1 | awk -F'|' '{  print $40}' `
   echo $mgrid
   var=`/usr/bin/more $HOME/pwd_date_chk/file2.txt  | awk -F'|' ' -v search="$mgrid" '{ $41 ~        search print $15}'`
   echo $var
   ```

Comment: You should avoid using old and obsoleted back tics, use parentheses like this:  `mgrid=$(echo $file1 | awk -F'|' '{  print $40})`.  You do not need to `echo` data to `awk` and always use quotes around variable, so this would then be: `mgrid=$(awk -F'|' '{print $40} <<< "$file1")`

Answer (score 0):

`awk` can read the input from file. No need to use `more`. You can try this,

```
mgrid=`echo $file1 | awk -F'|' '{  print $40}' `
echo $mgrid
var=`awk -F'|' -v search="$mgrid" '$41 ~ search {print $15}' $HOME/pwd_date_chk/file2.txt`
echo $var
```

Comment: I am having trouble in reading the external variable. it is giving error in the syntax .i doubt that -v option is not acceptable. is there any other alternative ??